# SwiftUI TabView sends enter to button on wrong tab?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm writing a Multiplatform SwiftUI app. It has 3 tabs organized in a TabView.

All 3 tabs have several buttons with one button per tab set to `.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)`. On a Mac, (Or an iOS device with a hardware keyboard) the return/enter key is supposed to trigger the default button on the current tab.

However, I just discovered that when running on a Mac, the closure on the button on the first tab is always triggered, even if one of the other tabs is currently visible.

### EDIT:

The problem occurs in the Mac version of the project and also occurs in the iOS simulator if you select "Connect Hardware Keyboard" in the sim. I don't have an easy way to connect a hardware keyboard to my phone, so I haven't tested that case yet. I may have to borrow a Bluetooth keyboard from another system and connect it to my phone to try that case.

Please tell me this is a SwiftUI bug?

Below is a single-file SwiftUI app that demonstrates the behavior described. To use this code, create a SwiftUI project (either Mac or Multiplatform) and copy the code below in to replace the body of the ContentView.

To see the behavior, launch the app on your Mac, select tab 2, and press enter on the keyboard. The message changes to "Tab 1 button pressed" even though tab 2 is on-screen and tab 2 should not be in the responder chain.

You can download a working version of the project from Github at [this link](https://github.com/DuncanMC/TabViewTest.git).

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message: String = "Starting message"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState = AppState()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                Tab1View(appState: appState)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        Text("Tab 1")
                    }
                Tab2View(appState: appState)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                        Text("Tab 2")
                    }
            }
            Text(appState.message)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Tab1View: View {
    
    var appState: AppState
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tab 1")
            Button {
                print("In tab 1 button action")
                appState.message = "Tab 1 button pressed"
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
        }
    }
}

struct Tab2View: View {
    var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tab 2")
            Button {
                print("In tab 2 button action")
                appState.message = "Tab 2 button pressed"
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Probably because you are asking if your code has a bug but to get your code we would have to ask you for it.

Comment: No, I am asking if SwiftUI has a bug on Mac OS. I don't think there is any app-level code that could cause a button in an inactive tab in a tab view to respond to key events. It shouldn't be in the responder chain. I'll create a minimal reproducible example and post it.

Comment: Maybe it wouldn’t be the first time. There was a huge bug where the “if” button was activating in the “else” view a while back.

Comment: Use StateObject instead of ObservedObject when you initialize in a View that is an easy leak.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that it works on iOS, I highly suspect this is a SwiftUI bug. I would work around it by checking the currently selected tab, and make sure that there is only one `.defaultAction` at a time.

```
@State var selection = 0

...

TabView(selection: $selection) {
    Button("Button 1") {
        print("Tab 1")
    }
        .keyboardShortcut(selection == 0 ? .defaultAction : nil)
        .tag(0)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Foo", systemImage: "globe")
        }
    
    Button("Button 2") {
        print("Tab 2")
    }
        .keyboardShortcut(selection == 1 ? .defaultAction : nil)
        .tag(1)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Bar", systemImage: "rectangle")
        }
}
```

If the buttons are buried deep in the view hierarchy, you can make your own environment key to indicate `isSelectedTab`.

```
struct SelectedTabKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isSelectedTab: Bool {
        get { self[SelectedTabKey.self] }
        set { self[SelectedTabKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    ViewForTab1()
        .environment(\.isSelectedTab, selection == 0)
        .tag(0)
        .tabItem { ... }
    ViewForTab2()
        .environment(\.isSelectedTab, selection == 1)
        .tag(1)
        .tabItem { ... }
}
```

Then you can read `@Environment(\.isSelectedTab)` in your subviews.

Comment: Note that I misspoke. It misbehaves on both iOS and macOS. I still think it's a SwifTUI bug.

Comment: Your suggested approach doesn't work for a multi-window macOS app because the selected tab gets reset to the default each time you change the front-most window.